# How to find the region type (state, province,region) in Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to auto complete a web form. 
I want to label a region field properly depending on the result of the auto complete. Is there a way to make a query to return a place in a state, a province or a region? if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: It might help to show what you've got so far. I believe the Google Maps API returns [address components](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types) labelled `administrative_area_level_{1-4}`.

Comment: Yes It only return a place object with administrative area names but not their regional type. I left it up in case i missed something, but i think it is not doable as of today.